# WP All in one SEO, does it have a database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress for my website like a CMS,  also have installed ALL IN ONE SEO plugin.

I need to know if this plugin is using any kind of database, where i can retrieve description, keywords, seo title etc, for a specified post  in the database.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: ? I suspect it's using the same database as WP :) Look into it and search for the relevant table. Or maybe I just misunderstood the question, might as well be

Comment: Hello, but how can i find the keywords, or description that i have inserted in WP at all in one seo fields for a specified post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it uses your WP database.
aioseop_mrt_fix_meta function inside all_in_one_seo_pack.php updates values of wp_postmeta table.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, The All in One Seo plugin writes the following information under "meta_key" column

1. _aioseop_title : title
2. _aioseop_description : description
3. _aioseop_keywords : keywords

in wp_postmeta table in wordpress DB.